# How to allow textbox caret positioning (via mouseclick) when parent element is draggable

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, draggable

Ref. http://jsfiddle.net/a4LJv/2/

In IE/Firefox, having a parent element's draggable attribute equal to `true` prevents manual textbox caret positioning via mouse-clicks (keyboard arrows work fine). Chrome does not exhibit this behavior. I'm curious whether the former browsers have the proper implementation or if this is unexpected behavior. Also, my current workaround is to disable the draggable attribute on `mousedown` and re-enable on `mouseup`.

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#draggable "By default, only text selections, images, and links can be dragged. For all others elements, the event ondragstart must be set in order to the drag and drop mechanism to work, as shown in this comprehensive example."

Perhaps having the `draggable` attribute on an `li` is not supported?

Comment: @kendaleiv Those elements have exclusive default-support. Any other element is draggable, but requires the attribute and event-handler in order to do something.

Answer (score 0):

second workaround is to remove `drag` event from directly `textarea` like this:

```
$('textarea').on('dragstart', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

don't have IE to test, but it works for FF.

Comment: This just prevents dragging of selected text in the textarea. The issue is not with drag-related events on the textarea, however. A textarea with a parent-element having drag-events is what causes the text-caret issue.

Comment: I assigned you the bounty because you atleast attempted to answer. Enjoy the 20% bump for being brave.